# iOS coredata sort descriptor using part of a date?

Tags: ios, sorting, core-data, nssortdescriptor

In my app, I have a table view that shows a person's activities over time.  I want to sort the data by day, then by first name.  Problem is, I need to store the an NSDate with time included for other reasons.

Right now, I have this:

```
August 18, 2014 11:02 AM  Bill B.
August 18, 2014 10:20 AM  John D.
August 18, 2014 10:05 AM  Adam S.
August 11, 2014 3:47 PM   Debbie B.
August 11, 2014 2:13 PM   Adam S.
```

I would like the sort to ignore the time and only evaluate the date.  Like this:

```
August 18, 2014  Adam S.
August 18, 2014  Bill B.
August 18, 2014  John D.
August 11, 2014  Adam S.
August 11, 2014  Debbie B.
```

Is it possible to construct a sort descriptor that looks only at the month, day & year of a core data date attribute?

Comment: Do you need the sort to go into a fetch request, or can you do it after objects have been fetched?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use an additional attribute `sortDate`. You calculate that attribute in the setter of `startDate` (or however you call your date attribute) of your object. 
That's the fastest way if you store more than a few objects in core data. You could use a transient property and calculate the value in a getter, but this has quite an impact on performance.

I use something like this in one of my apps:

```
- (void)setStartDate:(NSDate *)startDate {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"startDate"];
    [self setPrimitiveStartDate:startDate];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"startDate"];

    if (startDate) {
        NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
//      might want to save sortDate in UTC
//      calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
        NSDate *sortDate;
        if ([calendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&sortDate interval:NULL forDate:startDate]) {
            self.sortDate = sortDate;
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Can't create sort date from date %@", startDate);
        }
    }
    else {
        self.sortDate = nil;
    }
}
```

The fetchRequest would then use `sortDate` and `startDate` for sorting and `sortDate` for sectioning.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
NSSortDescriptor *sdSortDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sortDate" ascending:NO];
NSSortDescriptor *sdStartDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"startDate" ascending:NO];
request.sortDescriptors = @[sdSortDate, sdStartDate];

NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sortDate" cacheName:@"MyFancyViewControllerCache"];
```